# Struggling to get this CSS class selector to work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a CSS rule:

```
.ajaxwebfont a {text-transform:lowercase;}
```

The HTML that I had hoped it would match to is:

```
<a class="fa fa-check-square-o ss-prime ss-cmd ajaxwebfont" href="..">Click me</a>
```

As you can see there are other classes in the target element for such things as defining a webfont. However I had hoped that I only needed to match on "ajaxwebfont".

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: It should be `a.ajaxwebfont` because it is the `a` which has that class. `.ajaxwebfont a` would refer to any `a` tag within a parent element which has class as `ajaxwebfont`.

Comment: @Harry you should put that as an answer so you get due credit..

Comment: Well it'll +1 from me.

Comment: @Harry, you helped me, period, which I am most grateful for. So enjoy the points :) and the weekend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selector should be `a.ajaxwebfont` because it is the anchor (`a`) element which has that class.

`.ajaxwebfont a` would refer to any `a` tag within a parent element which has class as `ajaxwebfont`.

When you add a space between two values it means that second one is a child of the first like

```
.demo #sample /* refers an element with id=sample under a parent with class=demo */
a .demo /* refers an element with class=demo under a parent anchor tag */
```

Without space means both are of the same element.

```
a.ajaxwebfont /* refers an element with class=ajaxwebfont which is also an anchor tag */
.demo.ajaxwebfont /* refers an element with class=ajaxwebfont which also has clss=demo */
#demo.ajaxwebfont /* refers an element with class=ajaxwebfont which also has id=demo */
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what other classes are affecting it. If no other class is applying text-transform, you can just use `.ajaxwebfont`. If something is overriding that, you'll have to be more specific than whatever is overriding it.

and ofc as mentioned, the class comes after the element selector, but attached. `a.class`